# 301 Redirect working for links, but not subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Recently moved a site over from a subdomain into a subdirectory of the root domain.

`http://blog.domain.com` to `http://domain.com/blog`.

I dropped this into my `.htaccess` at `http://blog.domain.com`, so users going to articles with old URLs will be redirected accordingly.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://blog.\domain\.com
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/blog [R=301,L]
```

I am unable to figure out how to redirect `http://blog.domain.com` to `http://domain.com/blog`. The snippet above does not do that. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```